# Proving the function is not surjective.

Tags: calculus, functions

$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$

It is given that $f(x)$ is symmetric about the line $x=a$, we need to prove that our function is not surjective.

If you try to visualize, for the function being onto it has to tend $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ for at least one point each for $x>a$ (as $f(x-a)=f(x+a)$, it has to take all values for $x>a$). So let us say that as $x\to +\infty\;\&\;y\to\infty$, so another point which is finite (and $x>0$) tends to $-\infty$ making the function undefined at that which is not possible.

I want to know if there is a more mathematical way to prove this, and also the function can be any function (even discontinuous).

Comment: What do you mean by a function is **into**? It is not clear what you mean, how can a function be symmetric about a horizontal line?

Comment: What do you mean that the function is symmetric about the line =?  From the way i read it this wouldn't be a function.

Comment: @copper.hat : I wanted to refer into as not surjective

Comment: @Q the Platypus , copper.hat : i corrected the mistake , it's x=a.

Comment: @aryanbansal, don't write '$\mathbb R$ is the set of real numbers' because it's a standard, normed notation all over the world and everybody should now that.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that it is not *injective*?

Comment: @AD I did not mean that , it was that i was disproved by '@'ingix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to prove is not correct. Take the function

$$f(x)=|x-a|\cos(x-a)$$

This is symmetric about the axis $x=a$ and nevertheless onto $\mathbb R$. To see that it is onto, consider that it can take arbitrarily high values for $x=a+2\pi n, n \in \mathbb N$, as we have $f(a+2\pi n)=|2\pi n|$ (as the cosine becomes $1$) and also arbitrariliy low values for $x=a+\pi+2\pi n, n \in \mathbb N$, as we have $f(a+\pi+2\pi n)=-|\pi+2\pi n|$ (as the cosine becomes $-1$). Since $f$ is continuous, it will take any value in between, so any value of $\mathbb R$ will be taken.

Your visualization is incorrect in that it assumes a function will need to tend to anything while $x$ tends to $+\infty$. As my example shows, it can osciallate widely, and thus take both arbitrarily high and low values.

Comment: Thanxx a lot bro!!!